# Training Data Recommendations for Text classification using Azure Machine learning

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

We want to work on a text classification problem using Azure machine learning. The problem that we have is client has ONLY approx 1300 rows of data for training.

We have 2 questions
So considering the few rows for training, do we have any recommendation on the training data? 
Any suggestions on how to handle a problem like this in AML?

Attachment shows the training data distribution across 15 categories.

[image: Data distribution across 15 categories]

Update:
we have added all categories with small data volume into a super category and have made the training data to have only 5 categories. Even then we are having an over all accuracy of 30%. Any Ideas on how we can improve overall accuracy of the AML model?

Comment: Can the categories be merged into fewer categories?